# Converting a pandas dataframe with a string type, three level MultiIndex into numeric type objects

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with a three level MultiIndex that looks like this:

```
gene            TIMP2      VEGFA       VIM  
2  TGFb 0.1  0.035655   0.876214 -0.158406  
        1    0.087623   1.049764  0.039158  
        10   0.054119   0.887348 -0.052608  
24 TGFb 0.1  0.148470   0.565379  0.157153  
        1    0.233250   0.540806  0.206030  
        10   0.378658   0.861429  0.132580  
48 TGFb 0.1 -0.203006   0.359409 -0.144209  
        1   -0.068495   0.845802 -0.093910  
        10  -0.105295   0.676591 -0.166819  
6  TGFb 0.1  0.060129   1.766071  0.097548  
        1    0.075760   1.656494  0.026664  
        10  -0.029685   1.284003 -0.008032  
   NaN  NaN  2.000000  12.000000  0.000000
```

The only problem is that because of the way I've built the MultiIndex (which is in-bedded into larger code so its difficult to paste here), the numbers in the index are strings. How do I convert the outer level to integer and the inner level to float? It sounds trivial but I'm having a lot of difficulty finding the solution. Thanks

Comment: Could you not convert the dtype to numeric prior to setting them as the indices? The issue here is that the multi-index is probably sorted alphabetically rather than numerically so even if you overwrote them now, you're going to get unexpected behaviour when you slice the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx.levels[0].astype(int), level=0) \
                   .set_levels(idx.levels[2].astype(float), level=2)
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you (again =])